# Make queries in hive run in parallel

Tags: hadoop, hive

I used hive for some time, however, never thought about this. I am trying to make queries in hive -f sql-file run in parallel? anyone know how to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

@user1653240 In order to run independent queries at the same time, what I am doing is:

- Put queries into different files, for example, `select count(1) from
  t1` -> file1.sql, `select count(1) from t2` -> file2.sql
- Use **nohup** and **&** commands. Take file1.sql and file2.sql as example,
  run: `nohup hive -f file1.sql & nohup hive -f file2.sql`, which will
  run these two queries in parallel.
- If you want to run in the background, just add one **&** in the end. For
  example: `(nohup hive -f file1.sql & nohup hive -f file2.sql) &`

Answer (score 0):

Hive will covert the HiveQL queries into MapReduce job and MapReduce jobs can run in parallel based on the size of the cluster and the type of scheduler configured. So, the Hive queries will automatically run in parallel on the Hadoop cluster.

Comment: I meant to run independent queries in the file in parallel. For example:

1) SELECT COUNT(1) FROM t1;
2) SELECT COUNT(1) FORM t2;

I want to run 1) and 2) in parallel so that 1) does not block 2).

Comment: Open two separate Hive shells and execute the HiveQL queries.

Comment: That is definitely one way, is there a way to make queries in a sql file non-blocking? For example, specify some Hive flag ...

Answer (score 0):

Any query on Hive gets compiled to Map-Reduce and run on Hadoop. Map-reduce is a parallel processing framework, therefore each of your Hive queries will run and process data in parallel.

The same question I asked but in some different manner. For more detail you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550898/is-it-possible-to-execute-hive-queries-parallelly-by-writing-seperate-mapreduce).

Answer (score 0):

Hive query planner should be able to parallelise things in specific cases. You need to set config option though:

```
hive.exec.parallel

Default Value: false
Added In: Hive 0.5.0

Whether to execute jobs in parallel.  Applies to MapReduce jobs that can run in parallel, for example jobs processing different source tables before a join.  As of Hive 0.14, also applies to move tasks that can run in parallel, for example moving files to insert targets during multi-insert.
```

taken from https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties

If you want to run totally independent queries in parallel, it might be the best option to run it as separate jobs from separate files as other suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I chose to do as I couldn't find a way to do it from the hive itself. Just replace filenames / database with the one in your case.

```
# This file should have all the queries separated with semicolon ';'
queries=`cat queries_file.sql`
count=0
while true; do
    ((count++))
    query=`echo ${queries} | cut -d';' -f${count}`
    if [ -z "${query}" ]; then
        echo "Completed executing ${count} - 1 queries."
        exit
    fi  
    echo "${query}"
    hive --database "your_db" -e "${query};" &

    # This is optional. If you want to give some gap, say after every 5
    # concurrent queries, use this. Or remove next 4 lines.
    mod=`expr ${count} % 5`
    if [ ${mod} -eq 0 ]; then
        sleep 30
    fi  
done
```

**Edit:**

Pretty old thread but still thought of updating the better solution for others. `xargs` can be used to achieve this instead of the custom code I pasted. Assuming all the queries in the file end with a semicolon, following xargs command can be used:

`cat queries.hql | sed 's/;$//g' |  xargs -d';' -n1 -I{} -P20 -r bash -c "hive --database ${your_db} -e '{}'"`

where `-P20` states that 20 queries are to be run in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

> No doubt excellent approach to execute hive queries in
>   parallel but how we insure that all queries in queries_file.sql
>   executed without any error.

In a sequence mode I use to ensure

```
hive -f queries_file.sql
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ] 
        then 
        echo "Failed!!"
        GOTO ERROR:
fi
```

successfull execution is very important if you want to perform some action afterwards.

For example:
-- Merge_Calculated_KPI.SQL (contain a Single query which is dependent on the above.)

```
hive -e "Drop table SANDBOX.status;  Create table SANDBOX.status as Select 10 as Query1 ,FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) AS UPDATE_TS FROM Metadata.DUMMY;"

sh exec_parralel.sh

hive -e "USE SANDBOX; INSERT INTO table SANDBOX.status Select 50 as Query1 ,FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) AS UPDATE_TS FROM Metadata.DUMMY;"
```

**OUTPUT**

query1  update_ts
- 0 10  2020-04-27 14:44:33
- 1 20  2020-04-27 14:45:04
- 4 30  2020-04-27 14:48:06
- 2 40  2020-04-27 14:46:06
- 3 50  2020-04-27 14:47:06

**Notice that last statement 50 executed quite early. it should be like 
10,
20,30,40 
50**

**Reference**
exec_parralel.sh

```
queries=`cat /Hadoop_SAN/TU_Prod/TMP/queries_file.sql`
count=0
while true; do
    ((count++))
    query=`echo ${queries} | cut -d';' -f${count}`
    if [ -z "${query}" ]; then
        echo "Completed executing." $count
        exit
    fi
   echo "${query}"
hive --database "Default" -e "${query};"  &
done
exit 0
```

Comment: The "Notice ..." part reads like this is a problem description instead of an answer. If you intend this to answer the question then please [edit] and make that more obvious.